RHEL8 + rsyslog: How to "tag" log records based on IP address of interface used by incoming TCP/UDP 514 syslog client traffic
I have a situation in which I have 3 different rsyslog servers, each of which ingests incoming syslog traffic from other "client" servers, network devices, etc. all via both TCP and UDP port 514. Traffic from each client device is then stored in its own uniquely-named logfile.
All 3 of these servers are in the same IP subnet.
I've received notice that the above 3 servers need to be consolidated into a single NEW rsyslog (RHEL8) Linux server. Timeframes do not permit going to each syslog client system and changing their destination syslog server to the new syslog server; that will have to be performed over a period of time due to the daunting administrative task of changing 400+ client servers/devices.
I'm planning on doing the following:

Prepare a new rsyslog server, testing, etc. Have the 3 IP addresses
for the existing servers "ready to go" as secondary IP addresses on
this new, but commented out in the network configuration. The
rsyslog configuration will also be setup and ready to go to accept
incoming syslog traffic on any of the 3 secondary IP addresses.

Shutdown the existing 3 rsyslog servers, and just before shutdown,
via their system consoles, change each network interface IP to a
non-interfering IP address. This is to prevent a clash of addresses
should the old server be accidentally brought up. Note: This
will all be setup, tested, configs made right, etc. in a TEST
environment before trying in PRODUCTION.

Within minutes of step #2, bring up the new rsyslog server with the
3 secondary IP addresses active so that this new server can receive
the syslog traffic that used to flow to the 3 formerly active
separate servers.


===========
Question: Is there a way to configure rsyslog to ID or "tag" the incoming syslog traffic so that I can later tell which of the 3 incoming secondary addresses was used for the traffic?
I'd like to use that "incoming ip address" information to either add that info to each client logfile name, and/or to actually modify each log record stored in the logfile.
BTW, in my test environment, I DO NOT have separate sub-interfaces defined for each of the secondary IP addresses - the single NIC interface simply has each secondary IP addresses added in a fashion that doesn't create a new interface name associated with each secondary address. I can have named sub-interfaces if that is what is needed in order to accomplish the tagging.
Thanks!

I would try this approach if it's possible:

Set up three additional imudp listeners in rsyslogd, each bound to a specific local IP Address (and with the IpFreeBind option enabled, preferably) and each with a distinct Name string. Do the same for imtcp.

Now you should be able to use the inputname property to determine which listener has received the message.



You could also try to reduce the switchover downtime by bringing up the IP addresses on the new system before they're removed from the old servers, then using arping to have the new server send a few "unsolicited ARP" packets (to make the router learn the new IP-MAC association).
Another way to have instant switchover would be to set up the nearby router to DNAT traffic for the three old addresses towards different UDP ports of your new server (again using three UDP listeners but this time on same IP address and different port numbers). This should be temporary until a non-NAT approach can be set up, but it would do the job.

in my test environment, I DO NOT have separate sub-interfaces defined for each of the secondary IP addresses - the single NIC interface simply has each secondary IP addresses added in a fashion that doesn't create a new interface name associated with each secondary address. I can have named sub-interfaces if that is what is needed in order to accomplish the tagging.

I don't think that would be useful. Sub-interfaces are practically a kernel 2.2.x relic; in modern systems they're just emulated using address "label" parameters. (That is, creating a sub-interface "eth0:2" via ifconfig still adds the address to eth0 in reality, only with label "2".)

On the old systems, I may just get some temporary (but valid) addresses and change to those, thus no conflicts with the new machine using the old addresses as secondaries, and I can still SSH to those old systems, if needed, before any decommissioning.
